# Can Firebase give manually added objects an unique key?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Is it possible when adding data manually to the Firebase database, through the dashboard, to let Firebase give each new object an unique key?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot. To achieve this, you need to use the `push()` method programmatically. This method will generate a unique key that can be saved in your database and used later in your project.

Please see [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) regarding saving data into a Firebase database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I was hoping that it is possible but I will insert my data with the push method.

Comment: Have to wait another 9 minutes to accept your answer. But I will come back later to do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

To create a randomly generated key you need to use `childByAutoId()` 
This will return a Firebase reference you could use and which will return the key with it's .key property

```
let createAutoID = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("orders").childByAutoId()

createAutoID.child("someOtherChild").setValue()
```

See documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data)

Comment: The question is about generating a random key from `Firebase console`, which is not possible.